# JpaItemReader process each element with a specific value

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

In my batch process data from a sql database has to be selected and be exported as a xml file. Therefore, I have to select all data for one parent element, to be able to export the parent node and all child nodes as xml.

I have a table like the following example:

```
|key|parent|child|
------------------
|yxc|par001|chi01|
|xcv|par001|chi02|
|cvb|par002|chi03|
|vbn|par003|chi04|
|bnm|par003|chi05|
```

Now I want to select every parent and its child elements. These should be processed after each other. For the above example table it should be: `par001` -> `par002` -> `par003`. The xml that will be exported should look like the following:

```
<par001>
    <chi01></chi01>
    <chi02></chi02>
</par001>
<par002>
    <chi03></chi03>
</par002>
...
```

How can I select the data so that I can process each parent element after each other? Is this possible with a JpaItemReader?

Comment: How would you do it *without* Spring Batch? Do you have a solution (an algorithm) to that problem?

Comment: Use a select statement to retrieve a list of parents. Then iterate over this list and select all the data for each parent. This data will then be mapped on an object where the parent fields have to be mapped only once. Child fields may be another object or are stored as lists in the parent.

Comment: I just had an idea to us a sql select statment to select the parent and concat the children in one field. This means I can use a JdbcItemReader to select the data. In the processor I have to split the children fields.

Comment: I added an answer. Did it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break the problem down into two steps:

- step 1 does a `select distinct(parent) from your_table` and stores the result in the job execution context (the result is a list of Strings or IDs, not entire items, so it's fine to store them in the execution context in order to share them with the next step)
- step 2 reads parent IDs from the execution context and iterate over them using an item reader. An item processor would enrich each item with its children before passing enriched items to a `StaxEventItemWriter`